# org.jboss.ws.WSException: Target endpoint address not set

Tags: web-services, soap-client, jboss5.x

I want to consume soap service and created stubs for that  (https). when I am invoking that service facing below error.

```
org.jboss.ws.WSException: Target endpoint address not set
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately [how JBossWS Native works](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossws/stack/native/tags/jbossws-native-3.1.2.SP15/modules/core/src/main/java/org/jboss/ws/core/jaxws/spi/ServiceDelegateImpl.java). When the Service is instantiated, access to the WSDL is attempted first. When this fails, we log a WARN saying **Cannot access wsdlURL:** but the Service is still initialized.

A workaround would be use a local WSDL to create the Service from and then the exception will be thrown when attempting to make the call as expected where you would retry because the Service object will always be correctly initialized using the local WSDL.

Comment: how do i use a local WSDL to create the Service from, can you please help me.? I created stubs using soapui.